# how to proper do a string concatenation in awk

Tags: string, awk, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate strings from a `.csv` file.
A simple example data file is:

```
$ cat a
100, 200, 300
400, 500, 600
```

And the first approach results in nothing.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="-"}{gsub(/ /, "");a=$1$2$3; print $a}' a
```

In the second approach I also did not get the expected result.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="-"}{gsub(/ /, "");a="$1$2$3"; print $a}' a
100,200,300
400,500,600
```

Expected result would be

```
100200300
400500600
```

If the `.csv' file has strings instead of numbers, I still don't get the expected result. Some commas (,) are inserted in the middle, even though I've set the output field separator as dash (-).

```
$ cat b
AAA, BBB, CCC
DDD, EEE, FFF

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="-"}{gsub(/ /, "");a=$1$2$3; print $a}' b
AAA,BBB,CCC
DDD,EEE,FFF
```

In this case, the expected result was

```
AAABBBCCC
DDDEEEFFF
```

Comment: What do you think `print $a` does?

Comment: Right. There should be no `$` in there.

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $1""$2""$3}' file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This works if there are no space, so `awk -F', *' '{print $1$2$3}'` should do.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you. Adding the same multi-field separator, for an unknown number of fields `awk -F', *' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s",$i; print""}' file` should work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F', *' -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1' a
100200300
400500600

awk -F', *' -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1' b
AAABBBCCC
DDDEEEFFF
```

Set Field Separator to comma and zero or more spaces and Output Fields Separator to nothing, then recreate the fields and print them.

Or just remove comma space

```
awk '{gsub(/, */,"")}1' a
sed 's/, *//g' a
```

Comment: in my final script I want to assign the string concatenation to variable to be used elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

It was just an extra `$`.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="-"}{gsub(/ /, "");a=$1$2$3; print a}' a
100200300
400500600
```

Comment: This is the wrong approach. The OFS is doing nothing, and if you were going to do a gsub() then that's ALL you'd have to do (but include , in the regexp) or don't do a gsub and add `" "` to the FS. See [@Jotne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57896879/1745001) for a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/ /,""); print $1$2$3}' file

100200300
400500600
```